# python structure JSON serializing issue

Tags: python, json, serialization

I've got a cache dictionary that stores a 3-element list for each key: `[value, date_created, hits]`. The cache communication is done via JSON. There is a `items` command in the cache that shall return all items. This is the set cache method:

```
@status
def handle_set(self, key, value):
    self.data[key] = [value, datetime.datetime.now(), 0]
    return
```

The problem occurs when I have a non-empty cache and I call `items` on it. Python datetime object is not serializable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 69, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 146, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = getattr(selectable, method)()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 460, in doRead
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "./server.py", line 17, in dataReceived
    result = getattr(self.factory, command)(**request)
  File "./server.py", line 35, in execute
    return json.dumps(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
exceptions.TypeError: datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 26, 11, 38, 42, 348094) is not JSON serializable
```

I have found a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable/15538391#15538391). But the thing I don't like in the accepted answer is that I have to provide a custom serializer.

in my cache I have different commands, but I'd like to use one JSON-formatting method for all cache commands. I'm afraid I'd have to do an if-cascade if I were to follow that answer.

Is there any way to override `datetime.datetime` to provide one simple method that will be used by JSON serializer? Or any better solution to this?

datetime.datetime JSON serialization could be as simple as `str(d)` for me (a string representation).

Comment: I don't understand _"in my cache I have different commands"_. I don't think you want to serialize the complete object along with the various methods attached. In this case, I would recommend writing a `MyClass.to_JSON` method which converts the `datetime` object to string via `d.isoformat()` and then a `@staticmethod` `MyClass.from_JSON` which converts it back using `dateutil.parser.parse(d_str)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally accepted approach is to subclass the default encoder.

```
import json

class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'): #handles both date and datetime objects
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif hasattr(obj, 'total_seconds'): #handles both timedelta objects
            return str(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal): #handles decimal timedelta objects
            return float(obj)
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

To use the new class:

```
context['my_json_data'] = json.dumps(my_python_data, cls=CustomJSONEncoder)
```

The issue is that there is no universally accepted way to represent a date, so Python forces you to choose.  While it can be frustrating, Python is forcing you to accept the fact that any time you convert a date you're making a choice.